# Why does a Hall sensor use a solid magnet?

Tags: motor, sensor, control, hall-effect, magnet

I have disassembled two motor circuits that use a Hall sensor. One is a cooling [fan blower](https://www.mouser.co.il/datasheet/2/570/08028gs-1512267.pdf) and the other is a 230 VAC motor.

The blower has a brushless motor and has its Hall sensor on the stator board with the coils. The rotor is a solid magnet cylinder encompassing the whole stator.

The motor had its Hall sensor (SOT23, unrecognizable marking) facing a solid disc.

How does it detect turns (or calculate speed) if the magnet is a solid body?

Comment: A 'solid body' can still be magnetically non-uniform. If it was uniform, it wouldn't work, therefore it must be non-uniform.

Comment: Because liquid, gas, and plasma magnets were inconvenient for various reasons.

Comment: Are you sure the hall sensor is detecting the disk, and not the magnetic rotor? The person who invents a magnet with only one pole will be rich, indeed.

Answer (score 7):

Magnets can be diametrically magnetized.

[image: diametrically magnetized]